# How to Read the Content of a Remote Web Page Tag by Tag in asp.net using c#?

Tags: asp.net, url, remote-access

I want to read the content of the Remote Webpage in asp.net using C#. I have read it using the following code in asp.net.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TheUrl = "http://www.demosite.com/Default.aspx";
        string response = GetHtmlPage(TheUrl);
        Response.Write(response);

    }
static string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
    {

        String strResult;
        WebResponse objResponse;
        WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        return strResult;
    }
```

Here i get the whole content of the Remote WebPage now i want read the content Tag by tag and get Only the Content of it. Is it possible?

Help Appreciated...!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per @atticae suggestion to use the HTML Agility Pack to parse HTML, here's a simple example that may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/10579599/122005

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to traverse the elements. It's the best way to parse HTML.

You should be able to get all the text nodes with

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']")
```