# fetching data from web site

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i fetch data from http://www.vaktija.ba/mobile/ but i dont get the body part of the website
i just get title

here is my code

```
public void getpage() {
    Uri u = new Uri("http://www.vaktija.ba/mobile/");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);
     client.DownloadStringAsync(u);
}

private void DownloadStringCallback2(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
     //data.Text = e.Result;
     data.Text = Regex.Replace(e.Result, "<[^>]*>", "");
}

private void but_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    getpage();
}
```

what should i do to get body part are there any other way to do that

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579292/how-to-read-the-website-content-in-c

Comment: i didnt ask how to filter.i dont understand why i dont get body part of the website

Comment: The body part is removed by the regular expression replace method.

Comment: in that question you can get other ways to do that. you have mentioned that any other way in your question

Comment: when i didnt use replace method i still dont get body part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in your call back function.

```
string html = e.Result;
       string theBody = "";
       RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
       Regex regx = new Regex("<body>(?<theBody>.*)</body>", options);
       Match match = regx.Match(html);
       if (match.Success)
       {
           theBody = match.Groups["theBody"].Value;
       }
```

"theBody" variable will have inner html of body tag.

Comment: i got nothing in result.

Comment: when i just print data.Text = e.Result; (whole html page) I still dont get body part

Comment: ok ok i get the result with your code i forget to print in my textblock